# Failed Upgrade from SQL Server 2005 sp2 to SQL Server 2005 sp4

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-pack

SQL Server Standard 2005 sp2 32bit running on Windows 2003 Standard 32bit service pack 2.

I attempted a service pack upgrade from sp2 to sp4 using **SQLServer2005SP4-KB2463332-x86-ENU.exe** and received the following error:

```
Property(S): UpgradeInstruction = Connect to SQL instance MYSERVER as sysadmin
Launch SQL statement USE master
Launch script file d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install\sysdbupg.sql
Launch script file d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install\DbEngine_hotfix_install.sql
Launch script file d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install\repl_hotfix_install.sql
Stop service MSSQLSERVER
Property(S): SqlUpgradeMessage = SQL Server Setup failed to parse the SQL script "d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install\DbEngine_hotfix_install.sql". The error code is The system cannot find the file specified.
. To continue, correct the problem, and then run SQL Server Setup again.
```

The file **d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install\DbEngine_hotfix_install.sql** is missing and I have tried this upgrade from two different **SQLServer2005SP4-KB2463332-x86-ENU.exe** files.

After the service pack install completed, I was able to start SQL Server and the version was 9.0.5000.  There were no other errors in the logs, but I did rollback the server using a vmware snapshot taken before installing SP4.

I googled around but didn't find anything useful.

Why would the file **DbEngine_hotfix_install.sql file** be missing from the service pack installation ?

Comment: I'd try upgrading from SP2 to SP3, then SP3 to SP4, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I actually did consider that shouldn't be necessary right?  I'd like to understand what happened or someone tell me that sp2 to sp3 and then sp3 to sp4 is the only solution

Comment: [This user](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/25d71567-454e-40cf-9bcc-58aef09c464a) appears to have had the same issue, but I'm not sure there's anything of usefulness in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Almost every time I've had an SP installation issue on a stand-alone server, it was because the resource database was moved or it was not in the same directory as the master database.

Many articles I'm finding correlate your error to this exact conclusion including [this one](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=105723).

I would start there and if you find it to be the case, move the system databases back to where the resource database is.

If that doesn't work, try re-applying SP2.  If all of the components weren't patched during the SP2 upgrade, you could experience this issue.

Lastly, verify service account permissions and permissions of the account you are running the SP4 with.